# Static Files Not Loading With URL Parameters

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I ran into a strange issue. My static files seem to be loading for my entire site, except for when I pass parameters into the URL route. For example...

Static files load:

```
('/profile', Profile)

class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('profile.html')
```

Static files do not load:

```
('/profile/(\d+)', Profile)

class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, user_id):
        self.render('profile.html')
```

Would anyone know why this is occurring? The `profile.html` remains constant through both calls.

Comment: How does the static-serving routing looks like in the `app.yaml` file?

Comment: Post a small relevant portion of your `profile.html`, you might be using relative paths, and so making lookups on `/profile/static/img.png` instead of `/static/img.png`.